# Adding 'Scale lines' to side of div to act as a scale for 'divs contents'

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I currently have [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hmtq3yk/2/) design in which will act like a 'scale' to visually tell me when my 'tank' is full.

*(I've used an internal bottom border to achieve the second colour within the div, and so getting the 'other colour' isn't the issue here - probably not the best option, but it works!)*

The div is set to be 500px tall, and I was looking to have 'scale lines' every 10/20px all the way up the side (similar to that of a thermometer gauge).

I'm not great with css/javascript/web design in general, and am totally bamboozaled as to how to make/create something like

[image]

My current css is:

```
.addDropShadowToTank{
     box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #393939;
     border-radius:30px;
     display:table-cell;
     font-size:large;
     width:350px;
     height:500px;
     vertical-align:middle; 
     text-align:center; 
     background-color: #fa5858;
}
```

I was thinking something like a Z-index would help, but even this simple task seems beyond me :(

And even if i *did* somehow manage this, how would I make the lines appear **evenly** across the height of the div?

Something like:

```
 Current:            Wanted:
 +--------+          +--------+
 |        |          |       _|  <-- how to achieve this sort of scale design?
 |        |          |        |
 |        |          |       _|
 |        |          |        |
 |        |          |       _|
 |wwwwwwww|          |wwwwwwww|
 |    O   |          |    O  _|
 |  O     |          |  O     |
 |     o  |          |     o _|
 | o      |          | o      |
 +--------+          +--------+
```

**Please Note**

I have updated the JSfiddle to show you the contents (it required removing some of the redundant javascript). In reality the percentage is calculated from my model's data and not hardcoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the scaling by using css gradients in combination with `background-size` without using any images.

You just adjust the `background-size` property to scale the background - if you want to have `20px` spacing between lines change the px value to `20px` - the solution is dynamic.

```css
 .thermometer {
position:relative;
width:200px;
height:300px;
border-radius:30px;
overflow:hidden;
background:green;
}
.fluid {
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
width:100%;
bottom:0;
left:0;
background:blue;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #393939;
}
.thermometer:after {
content:"";
z-index:1000;
width:50px;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
z-index:100;
right:0;
bottom:0;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 4%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 14%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 72%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 0) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(4%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(14%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(72%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 0)));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 4%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 14%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 72%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 0) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 4%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 14%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 72%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 0) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 4%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 14%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 72%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 0) 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 4%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 14%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 72%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 0) 100%);
background-size:5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="thermometer">
<div class="fluid" style="height:40%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MrCoder where are you stuck? The relevant css is the meter part - it should be positioned absolutely inside the parent div - note your parent div has to have position:relative set. I suggest you use the html provided in my fiddle and just adjust it to your design. You change the percentage through style attribute of the div, while keeping everything else in css classes.

Comment: @MrCoder I've added the bars to the side. Check the fiddle man.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63476/discussion-between-easwee-and-mrcoder).

Comment: Thanks again (you might want to update your fiddle also, for future users and all that :P). Code snippet works a treat!

Comment: @MrCoder np - updated with SO fiddle so it's all in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using which you can exactly achieve what you're trying to do. You can use the `:after` psuedo-selector on the `#myTank` element and apply an image-background on it which would be a scale image created using Photoshop or any other graphic software.

Here's the live **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hmtq3yk/14/)**.

```js
  var percent = 40;
  var cap = 100;
  percent = (percent / cap).toFixed(2);
  var width = percent * 500;


  document.getElementById("myTank").style["background-color"] = "green";

  document.getElementById("myTank").style["border-bottom"] = width + "px solid blue";
  document.getElementById("myTank").style["height"] = 500 - width + "px";
  document.getElementById("myPercentage").innerText = percent * 100 + "%";
```

```css
.addDropShadowToTank {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #393939;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: large;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fa5858;
}
div#myTank:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: url(http://s28.postimg.org/bclakfrvt/bars.png);
  width: 100%;
  height: 440px;
  background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
  margin-top: -120px;
  margin-left: 159px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float:right; padding-right:150px">
  <div id="myPercentage" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:large"></div>
  <div id="myTank" class="addDropShadowToTank"></div>
```

Comment: Seems to be what i'm looking for @Fahad, I can see only one *slight* issue which is if the screen is smaller than the div, the 'bars' position slides outside the 'tank'.

Comment: Would it be fine if the scale is on the left side instead of the right side?

Comment: I was just editing it and made it float to left. But 'conventionally', the scale usually appears on the right

Answer (score 0):

## Creating the initial scale lines without using an image

Avoiding using images, I've initially generated the following using the [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), filling the background with `#fa5858` and placing a `#000` gradient at every 10th percentile (from 10 to 90):

[image: Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator Result]

This gives us the following (somewhat ugly) CSS (which I've also applied to your [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/5hmtq3yk/24/)):

```css
figure {
    height: 500px;
    width: 350px;
  
 background: #fa5858; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fa5858 0%, #fa5858 9%, #fa5858 9%, #000000 10%, #fa5858 11%, #fa5858 19%, #000000 20%, #fa5858 21%, #fa5858 29%, #000000 30%, #fa5858 31%, #fa5858 39%, #000000 40%, #fa5858 41%, #fa5858 49%, #000000 50%, #fa5858 51%, #fa5858 59%, #000000 60%, #fa5858 61%, #fa5858 69%, #000000 70%, #fa5858 71%, #fa5858 79%, #000000 80%, #fa5858 81%, #fa5858 89%, #000000 90%, #fa5858 91%, #fa5858 100%, #fa5858 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fa5858), color-stop(9%,#fa5858), color-stop(9%,#fa5858), color-stop(10%,#000000), color-stop(11%,#fa5858), color-stop(19%,#fa5858), color-stop(20%,#000000), color-stop(21%,#fa5858), color-stop(29%,#fa5858), color-stop(30%,#000000), color-stop(31%,#fa5858), color-stop(39%,#fa5858), color-stop(40%,#000000), color-stop(41%,#fa5858), color-stop(49%,#fa5858), color-stop(50%,#000000), color-stop(51%,#fa5858), color-stop(59%,#fa5858), color-stop(60%,#000000), color-stop(61%,#fa5858), color-stop(69%,#fa5858), color-stop(70%,#000000), color-stop(71%,#fa5858), color-stop(79%,#fa5858), color-stop(80%,#000000), color-stop(81%,#fa5858), color-stop(89%,#fa5858), color-stop(90%,#000000), color-stop(91%,#fa5858), color-stop(100%,#fa5858), color-stop(100%,#fa5858)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #fa5858 0%,#fa5858 9%,#fa5858 9%,#000000 10%,#fa5858 11%,#fa5858 19%,#000000 20%,#fa5858 21%,#fa5858 29%,#000000 30%,#fa5858 31%,#fa5858 39%,#000000 40%,#fa5858 41%,#fa5858 49%,#000000 50%,#fa5858 51%,#fa5858 59%,#000000 60%,#fa5858 61%,#fa5858 69%,#000000 70%,#fa5858 71%,#fa5858 79%,#000000 80%,#fa5858 81%,#fa5858 89%,#000000 90%,#fa5858 91%,#fa5858 100%,#fa5858 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #fa5858 0%,#fa5858 9%,#fa5858 9%,#000000 10%,#fa5858 11%,#fa5858 19%,#000000 20%,#fa5858 21%,#fa5858 29%,#000000 30%,#fa5858 31%,#fa5858 39%,#000000 40%,#fa5858 41%,#fa5858 49%,#000000 50%,#fa5858 51%,#fa5858 59%,#000000 60%,#fa5858 61%,#fa5858 69%,#000000 70%,#fa5858 71%,#fa5858 79%,#000000 80%,#fa5858 81%,#fa5858 89%,#000000 90%,#fa5858 91%,#fa5858 100%,#fa5858 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fa5858 0%,#fa5858 9%,#fa5858 9%,#000000 10%,#fa5858 11%,#fa5858 19%,#000000 20%,#fa5858 21%,#fa5858 29%,#000000 30%,#fa5858 31%,#fa5858 39%,#000000 40%,#fa5858 41%,#fa5858 49%,#000000 50%,#fa5858 51%,#fa5858 59%,#000000 60%,#fa5858 61%,#fa5858 69%,#000000 70%,#fa5858 71%,#fa5858 79%,#000000 80%,#fa5858 81%,#fa5858 89%,#000000 90%,#fa5858 91%,#fa5858 100%,#fa5858 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #fa5858 0%,#fa5858 9%,#fa5858 9%,#000000 10%,#fa5858 11%,#fa5858 19%,#000000 20%,#fa5858 21%,#fa5858 29%,#000000 30%,#fa5858 31%,#fa5858 39%,#000000 40%,#fa5858 41%,#fa5858 49%,#000000 50%,#fa5858 51%,#fa5858 59%,#000000 60%,#fa5858 61%,#fa5858 69%,#000000 70%,#fa5858 71%,#fa5858 79%,#000000 80%,#fa5858 81%,#fa5858 89%,#000000 90%,#fa5858 91%,#fa5858 100%,#fa5858 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fa5858', endColorstr='#fa5858',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<figure></figure>
```

#### Example

[image: Initial Example]

## Ensuring the scale lines only appear on the last 10% of the element's width

The problem now is only making these lines not fill 100% of the width. I'm not sure of any way to do this in pure CSS unfortunately, so I've instead had to add a new element to your markup:

```
<div id="myTank" class="addDropShadowToTank">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Then ensure `overflow` was set to `hidden` on your `.addDropShadowToTank` element. Then finally give this new `div` element 100% `height` and 90% `width` with the same background colour as our `.addDropShadowToTank` element (which can be seen in [this JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/5hmtq3yk/26/)).

Here is the modified code snippet with this applied:

```css
figure {
    height: 500px;
    width: 350px;
  
 background: #fa5858; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fa5858 0%, #fa5858 9%, #fa5858 9%, #000000 10%, #fa5858 11%, #fa5858 19%, #000000 20%, #fa5858 21%, #fa5858 29%, #000000 30%, #fa5858 31%, #fa5858 39%, #000000 40%, #fa5858 41%, #fa5858 49%, #000000 50%, #fa5858 51%, #fa5858 59%, #000000 60%, #fa5858 61%, #fa5858 69%, #000000 70%, #fa5858 71%, #fa5858 79%, #000000 80%, #fa5858 81%, #fa5858 89%, #000000 90%, #fa5858 91%, #fa5858 100%, #fa5858 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fa5858), color-stop(9%,#fa5858), color-stop(9%,#fa5858), color-stop(10%,#000000), color-stop(11%,#fa5858), color-stop(19%,#fa5858), color-stop(20%,#000000), color-stop(21%,#fa5858), color-stop(29%,#fa5858), color-stop(30%,#000000), color-stop(31%,#fa5858), color-stop(39%,#fa5858), color-stop(40%,#000000), color-stop(41%,#fa5858), color-stop(49%,#fa5858), color-stop(50%,#000000), color-stop(51%,#fa5858), color-stop(59%,#fa5858), color-stop(60%,#000000), color-stop(61%,#fa5858), color-stop(69%,#fa5858), color-stop(70%,#000000), color-stop(71%,#fa5858), color-stop(79%,#fa5858), color-stop(80%,#000000), color-stop(81%,#fa5858), color-stop(89%,#fa5858), color-stop(90%,#000000), color-stop(91%,#fa5858), color-stop(100%,#fa5858), color-stop(100%,#fa5858)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #fa5858 0%,#fa5858 9%,#fa5858 9%,#000000 10%,#fa5858 11%,#fa5858 19%,#000000 20%,#fa5858 21%,#fa5858 29%,#000000 30%,#fa5858 31%,#fa5858 39%,#000000 40%,#fa5858 41%,#fa5858 49%,#000000 50%,#fa5858 51%,#fa5858 59%,#000000 60%,#fa5858 61%,#fa5858 69%,#000000 70%,#fa5858 71%,#fa5858 79%,#000000 80%,#fa5858 81%,#fa5858 89%,#000000 90%,#fa5858 91%,#fa5858 100%,#fa5858 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #fa5858 0%,#fa5858 9%,#fa5858 9%,#000000 10%,#fa5858 11%,#fa5858 19%,#000000 20%,#fa5858 21%,#fa5858 29%,#000000 30%,#fa5858 31%,#fa5858 39%,#000000 40%,#fa5858 41%,#fa5858 49%,#000000 50%,#fa5858 51%,#fa5858 59%,#000000 60%,#fa5858 61%,#fa5858 69%,#000000 70%,#fa5858 71%,#fa5858 79%,#000000 80%,#fa5858 81%,#fa5858 89%,#000000 90%,#fa5858 91%,#fa5858 100%,#fa5858 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fa5858 0%,#fa5858 9%,#fa5858 9%,#000000 10%,#fa5858 11%,#fa5858 19%,#000000 20%,#fa5858 21%,#fa5858 29%,#000000 30%,#fa5858 31%,#fa5858 39%,#000000 40%,#fa5858 41%,#fa5858 49%,#000000 50%,#fa5858 51%,#fa5858 59%,#000000 60%,#fa5858 61%,#fa5858 69%,#000000 70%,#fa5858 71%,#fa5858 79%,#000000 80%,#fa5858 81%,#fa5858 89%,#000000 90%,#fa5858 91%,#fa5858 100%,#fa5858 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #fa5858 0%,#fa5858 9%,#fa5858 9%,#000000 10%,#fa5858 11%,#fa5858 19%,#000000 20%,#fa5858 21%,#fa5858 29%,#000000 30%,#fa5858 31%,#fa5858 39%,#000000 40%,#fa5858 41%,#fa5858 49%,#000000 50%,#fa5858 51%,#fa5858 59%,#000000 60%,#fa5858 61%,#fa5858 69%,#000000 70%,#fa5858 71%,#fa5858 79%,#000000 80%,#fa5858 81%,#fa5858 89%,#000000 90%,#fa5858 91%,#fa5858 100%,#fa5858 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fa5858', endColorstr='#fa5858',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  
    overflow: hidden;
}

figure div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
  
    background: #fa5858;
}
```

```html
<figure>
    <div></div>
</figure>
```

We now have a black line appearing every 10% of the height, which is only displayed on the last 10% of the element's width.

#### Final Result

[image: Final Result]

---

> James, thank you for your answer. However, since i'm using a 'border-bottom' (see edited fiddle in question) - it means that the 'gradient lines' will only display section where there is 'air' in the tank...

For that we can add another element inside our tank.

First, begin by setting our `.addDropShadowToTank` element to `position: relative`, and then add the following:

```
<div id="myTank" class="addDropShadowToTank">
    <div></div>
    <span id="fill"></span>
</div>
```

We can now apply the following style to our `#fill` span:

```css
.addDropShadowToTank #fill {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0 , 255, 0.5);
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

This will make our fill colour slightly transparent (allowing us to see the scale lines below it). Now we can simply alter the JavaScript. Remove the `border` parts and the parts about setting the `height` on our `.addDropShadowToTank` element, and then add:

```
document.getElementById("fill").style["height"]=width +"px";
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/5hmtq3yk/30/).

Comment: James, thank you for your answer. However, since i'm using a 'border-bottom' (see edited fiddle in question) - it means that the 'gradient lines' will only display section where there is 'air' in the tank, and not throughout (the 'water' section). Removing the part of javascript to test something else, you are left with: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5hmtq3yk/28/) :(

Comment: thank you for you answer. It will be helpful for me in the future, but have gone with another answer on the basis that it also uses gradients.